# referencing three columns to same column in another table in sql server 2000

Tags: sql-server

I have a question on `SQL Server 2000`, i need to get an report from database. I have database called `Automation` where it contains set of tables to handle the queries of ticketing process of our application.

I need to extract a report from database that should contain *ticket number* and *user information* like who has entered, received, edited , reviewed that ticket.

I need these fields from the database

```
Ticketnumber
billnumber
companyname
enteredby(username)
entereddate
recievedby(username)
recieveddate
editedby(Employeename)
editeddate
reviewedby(ReviewerName)
revieweddate
postedby(Managername)
posteddate
```

I have three tables 
1> `VPP_VendorBilldetails`

```
BillentryID | ticketnumber | billnumber | VENDORNAME,BILLNUMBER,COSTCENTERNAME,BILLAMOUNT,TICKETDATE,BILLDATE | companyID(not companyname) | billdate | Enteredby(userid)| entereddate | recievedby(userid) | recieveddate | editedby(userid) | editeddate | reviewedby(userid) | revieweddate | postedby(userid) | posteddate
```

2> `Users`

```
UserID | employeeID | employeename |loginID| Password | usertype | status
```

3> `VPP_ClientCompanyDetails` :

```
companyid | companyname | companyaddress | status
```

I have written this query, but I am getting same employee name for all three categories :

```
  SELECT CLIENTCOMPANYNAME,  TICKETNUMBER,VENDORNAME,BILLNUMBER,COSTCENTERNAME,BILLAMOUNT,TICKETDATE,BILLDATE,
    RECIEVEDDATE,EMPLOYEENAME AS EXECUTIVENAME,
        VPP_VENDORBILLDETAILS.MODIFIEDDATE,
        EMPLOYEENAME AS REVIEWERNAME,EMPLOYEENAME AS POSTEDBY,POSTEDDATE,ERRORCODE,
        IMPACTCODE,ROOTCAUSE,REVIEWERREMARKS
        FROM 
    VPP_VENDORBILLDETAILS 

    INNER JOIN 
    VPP_CLIENTCOMPANYDETAILS 
    ON VPP_VENDORBILLDETAILS.BILLENTEREDCOMPANYID = VPP_CLIENTCOMPANYDETAILS.CLIENTCOMPANYID

    INNER JOIN USERS 
    ON VPP_VENDORBILLDETAILS.MODIFIEDBY = USERS.USERID

    WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),CONVERT(DATETIME,POSTEDDATE,103),101) 
        BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),getdate()-7,100),101) 
        AND CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),getdate()-1,100),101)

        AND VPP_CLIENTCOMPANYDETAILS.STATUS = 1 AND VPP_VENDORBILLDETAILS.STATUS = 1 AND USERS.STATUS = 1 AND ERRORCODE IS NOT NULL AND TALLYID IS NOT NULL

        ORDER BY CLIENTCOMPANYNAME ASC
```

Please check it and help me on this

Please help me to extract the report the above said tables..

Comment: No effort or attempt shown.

Comment: Hi Mitch.. this is my first tome to login and asking 4 a question.. please let me know what i have to mention ??

Comment: Simple: show us your attempt.

Comment: Mitch: please check above

Comment: Pleas help me on this

Comment: @shankarreshmimath You have not given actual table names while asking the question. Provide those.Where 'EMPLOYEENAME' field coming from?

Comment: @Ravi: I have updated these details above question, please check. EMPLOYEENAME IS COMING FROM USERS TABLE.. VPP_VENDORBILLDETAILS TABLE contain ticket details, userids in 6 fields with different names like EnteredBy,RecievedBy,ApprovedBy,ModifiedBy,REviewedBy,PostedBy fields. these all fields referencing to same user table.. please let me know if you need any more information.. do the needful ravi

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT CLIENTCOMPANYNAME,  TICKETNUMBER,VENDORNAME,BILLNUMBER,COSTCENTERNAME,BILLAMOUNT,TICKETDATE,BILLDATE,
    RECIEVEDDATE,U1.EMPLOYEENAME AS EXECUTIVENAME,
        VPP_VENDORBILLDETAILS.MODIFIEDDATE,
        U2.EMPLOYEENAME AS REVIEWERNAME,U3.EMPLOYEENAME AS POSTEDBY,POSTEDDATE,ERRORCODE,
        IMPACTCODE,ROOTCAUSE,REVIEWERREMARKS
        FROM 
    VPP_VENDORBILLDETAILS 

    INNER JOIN 
    VPP_CLIENTCOMPANYDETAILS 
    ON VPP_VENDORBILLDETAILS.BILLENTEREDCOMPANYID = VPP_CLIENTCOMPANYDETAILS.CLIENTCOMPANYID

    INNER JOIN USERS U1
    ON VPP_VENDORBILLDETAILS.recievedby = U1.USERID

    INNER JOIN USERS U2
    ON VPP_VENDORBILLDETAILS.MODIFIEDBY = U2.USERID

    INNER JOIN USERS U3
    ON VPP_VENDORBILLDETAILS.postedby = U3.USERID


    WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),CONVERT(DATETIME,POSTEDDATE,103),101) 
        BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),getdate()-7,100),101) 
        AND CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),getdate()-1,100),101)

        AND VPP_CLIENTCOMPANYDETAILS.STATUS = 1 AND VPP_VENDORBILLDETAILS.STATUS = 1 AND USERS.STATUS = 1 AND ERRORCODE IS NOT NULL AND TALLYID IS NOT NULL

        ORDER BY CLIENTCOMPANYNAME ASC
```

Comment: I got it.. Thank you very much .... thanks a lot... I never thought of doing like this.. super ravi.. Thanks a ton..

Comment: I have one more question, recently i have added four new fields to the 'VPP_VENDORBILLDETAILS' table, these four fields will update by reviewer from his login and i have made mandatory in the application, user has enter these details before processing next step... whts happening is that only 1 or 2 fields r updating not all and remaining becomes blank.. I dont know how to find this issue.. i will come to know when I generate the report for these details..

Comment: Did you check if all are getting passed to DB? Debug, you will find the solution.

Comment: Thanks ravi but I have tested the application before releasing to the users.. and all four fields are passing to DB ... but i dont know how users r using it ...